# How to get key from Hive box object and map it to specific field of the object?

Tags: database, flutter, flutter-hive

The box is auto-incrementing.

Let's say that I have an object like so:

```
@HiveType(...)
class Dummy {
  
  @HiveField(0)
  int id;

  @HiveField(1)
  String name;

}
```

I want Hive deserialization to map the `Dummy` object's key to `id` field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you inherit your class from HiveObject, then you can use built in property 'key'.

```dart
    @HiveType(...)
    class Dummy extends HiveObject{
      //id not needed anymore
   
      @HiveField(0)
      String name;
    
    }
    
    ...
    
    Box<Dummy> db = Hive.box<Dummy>('dummy');
    Dummy dummy = Dummy(name: "some text");
    db.add(dummy); //add assigns next integer as key

    //after storing object to a database, you can access its key using 'key' property
    int id = dummy.key;

    //another advantage of extending HiveObject, is that you can store or delete object from the database without accessing the box:
    dummy.name = "other text";
    dummy.save(); //put modified object into box
    dummy.delete(); //delete object from the database
```

Comment: The reply is much appreciated. I've switched to SQLite. I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
db.put(dummy.id, dummy);
```